# Create SmartArt from TreeView in C#

Tags: c#, .net, office-automation, office-pia

Is there a way to create a SmartArt Hierarchy chart in Word from a treeview that the user creates in a C# Windows Forms application?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Word._Application oWord;
    Word._Document oDoc;
    oWord = new Word.Application();
    oWord.Visible = true;
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add();

    // here try from 1 to 15 until you find the layout you are interested in...
    var myLayout = oDoc.Application.SmartArtLayouts[8];

    var smartArtShape = oDoc.Shapes.AddSmartArt(myLayout, 50, 50, 200, 200);

    smartArtShape.AlternativeText = "xxxx";
}
```

this puts in the document the `SmartArt` Shape configured to use the `layout` nr 8. It's not really well documented and I spent much time in finding the right articles and samples:

this is very important to understand that you cannot create a `SmartArtLayout` object with the `new` keyword but should use any of those provided by the Application's layout collection...
[Application.SmartArtLayouts Property (Word)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839192.aspx)

This is some background...
[Creating Custom SmartArt Layouts with Office Open XML for Office 2007 and Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg583880.aspx)

Good luck :)